# Pandoc-mode does not find pandoc-main-hydra/body

Tags: pandoc

In my org and tex files pandoc-mode shows up as an enabled minor mode.

However, when I try to run: "pandoc-main-hydra/body" emacs complains that ‘pandoc-main-hydra/body’ is not a valid command name.  (When I run this command using a shortcut, it states: "Wrong type argument: commandp, pandoc-main-hydra/body").

I've been trying to find what is the problem for a while but without any luck.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do `M-x locate-library RET pandoc-mode`: I had a very old pandoc-mode installed that did not use the hydra before. Now that I've cleaned up the old version and installed latest from Melpa, I get the hydra and  `pandoc-main-hydra/body` is defined for me.

Comment: With `locate-library` I removed two old pandoc-mode.el. THANKS! However, when I tried reinstalling pandoc-mode my system complains: "pandoc-mode.el:1605:1:Warning: the following functions are not known to be     defined: pandoc-input-format-hydra/body, pandoc-output-format-hydra/body,
    ebib

Comment: Are you installing the package from MELPA?

Comment: I am.  But suddenly (and mysteriously as far as I can see) it is working.  I had closed and open emacs a few times to make sure that it was not an issue with restarting the program.  But now it is working.  Thanks so much for your help.  (BTW... do you want to just write your comments as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Summarizing the comments as an answer]

Versions of `pandoc-mode` before April 1, 2015 did not include a hydra. The `hydra` branch was merged in version 2.12 of pandoc-mode. So if an earlier version of `pandoc-mode` is installed, then the hydra-related stuff (including `pandoc-main-hydra/body`) would just not be present. That was certainly the case for me (I had a version from 2012 - I neglected to record the version number) and apparently also for the OP.

I had a very old pandoc-mode installed that did not use the hydra. Now that I've cleaned up the old version and installed latest from Melpa, I get the hydra and `pandoc-main-hydra/body` is defined for me.

To clean up the files, find the location of the `pandoc-mode` files that you are using, by doing `M-x locate-library` RET `pandoc-mode`. Delete them and then install `pandoc-mode` from MELPA (or from the Github site https://github.com/joostkremers/pandoc-mode).

BTW, you can't query for the version of `pandoc-mode` from emacs: it is just a string like `Version: 2.31` at the top of the `pandoc-mode.el` file, so you just have to visit the file to get it.

Comment: I mostly accepted your edit (particularly the locate-library stuff) but cleaned up the rest a bit. Thank you for improving the answer!